# How the comparisons are made using custom comparator in a set

Tags: c++

```
struct student{
    string name;
    float cgpa;
    student(string name, float cgpa){
        this -> name = name;
        this -> cgpa = cgpa;
    }
};

struct comp{
bool operator () (const student& x, student y) {
if ( x.name == "Wang" )
            return 1;
if ( y.name == "Wang" )
            return 0;    
 return x.name < y.name;
    }
};

    set < student, comp > batch ;
    batch.insert(student("Wang", 8.1));
    batch.insert(student("Ming", 6.32));
    batch.insert(student("Bruce", 8.82));
    batch.insert(student("Pandora", 7.63));

    for(student i : batch)
        cout<< i.cgpa << '\t ';
```

I cannot understand how the comparisons are being made in the above program.THe output of the set comes out to be  8.1 8.82 6.32 7.63.I dont understand how the elements in the set are compared to give this output.Can somebody please elaborate this?

Comment: The comparator looks broken to me, it gives `"Wang" < "Wang" == true`.

Comment: The question was asked in a quiz i cant change the code

Comment: So correct answer should be UB as comparer doesn't respect prerequires.

Answer (score 0):

That comp tries to treat `"Wang"` in special way, as less than other strings.

As pointed by HolyBlackCat, the comparer is wrong as `"Wang" < "Wang" == true` whereas it should be false.

Can be fixed with:

```
struct comp
{
    bool operator () (const student& x, const student& y) {
        if (y.name == "Wang")
            return false;
        if (x.name == "Wang")
            return true;
        return x.name < y.name;
    }
};
```

Using tuple comparison avoids such mistake, so:

```
struct comp
{
    bool operator () (const student& lhs, const student& rhs) const
    {
        const bool lhs_is_not_wang = lhs.name != "Wang";
        const bool rhs_is_not_wang = rhs.name != "Wang";

        return std::tie(lhs_is_not_wang, lhs.name)
             < std::tie(rhs_is_not_wang, rhs.name);
    }
};
```

order is so

- `student("Wang", 8.1)` ("Wang" first, then in lexicographical order of name)
- `student("Bruce", 8.82)`
- `student("Ming", 6.32)`
- `student("Pandora", 7.63)`